# Synchronized Highchart Data Load issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to load 16991 data items and plot it on Synchronised Highcharts but its not loading the data at all.

I have attached json data file for the reference which can be downloaded using below link

```
https://ufile.io/8r8oe0d8
```

Source of Highchart:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/synchronized-charts/
```

Comment: Firstly, all relevant code needs to be in the question. Secondly, check for errors in the console. I'd assume this is simply due to the weight of data, though

Comment: Thirdly, try with 91 data items... if that works then try with 991, etc   - if it doesn't work then there's something else and the size of the data isn't relevant to the issue (yet).

Comment: I've used highcharts and highstocks before, and I had one data every 10 minutes on at least 3 years, which is way more than his. So, I don't think it's related to the data weight. Aside from that, you should post your code.

Comment: It works with 1000 data records but fails when it goes beyond that, data json file I have uploaded and rest of code for frontend is same as jsfiddle link which is provided by highchart itself by replacing json url call

Comment: Hi @NIket, Please try to disable `turboThreshold` property: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.turboThreshold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ppotaczek,  it worked for me.

I have implemented this

```
plotOptions:{
                series:{
                    turboThreshold:0//larger threshold or set to 0 to disable
                }
            }
```

And it plots full data.